# hotkey of kernel menuconfig searching from current path

Tags: linux-kernel, kbuild

From `make menuconfig`, the items shown was not in alphabetical order. It is not easy to search what we need. Is any better way hotkey to faster get cursor to the item we need.

Comment: Enter "/" command to find a config parameter and the tool will display  a choice of parameters matching your request. Yo wil'l get the help as well as the menu path to reach the parameters